# Display rendered node in view mode X in self node in View mode Y

Tags: nodes

How can I render a node in itself in a different view mode?

[image: Node in node]

Comment: Why would you want that? Can't you simply display fields A and B in teaser display, and fields A, B, C, D in full one? Why that nesting? and by the way, see [Lorem Ipsum](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lorem_ipsum) ([generator here](http://en.lipsum.com/)) ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you  want to do this job the one way is achieve  in `node.tpl.php` (and sub tpls like `yourcontenttype--node.tpl.php` ), and according to  [variables in node tpl](https://drupal.org/node/11816)
 you can use both  **teaser** or **full** mode of node .also you can add your desire variable in theme preprocess ... , there is another  ways to do this with more developing solution